# 404 page not found Codeigniter Controller

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, ubuntu-12.04

I have a simple Codeigniter application.

Its default controller is *login*. When the application opens in a browser it loads the default controller and its view. But when I'm going to open another controller function, its showing 404 page not found.

This application works fine on my local PC. But on the Client Live Server this problem occurs. Client server is using Ubuntu 12.04.

Sample code

```
 class Login extends CI_Controller{
        function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();
        }
        function index(){
          $this->load->view('login/index');
        }
}
```

View file:

```
 <table>
       <tr>
          <td>Username: </td>
          <td><?php form_input('txt_username',set_value('txt_username',isset($row->username)?$row->username:''));?> </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Username: </td>
          <td><?php form_password('txt_username',set_value('txt_username',isset($row->password)?$row->password:''));?> </td>
       </tr>
      <tr>
<td colspan=2>for register click
 <a href=<?php echo site_url('registers/index');?>>Register</a></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Register Controller:

```
class Registers extends CI_Controller{
   function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
   }
   function index(){
    $this->load->view('register/index');
   }
}
```

When I click on Register link or other link in Menu showing 404 not found.But in my pc it is working fine.

Comment: yes. I checked.view files are uploaded correctly. I've tried this application in other servers. There it works good. But in client server it causes the problem

Comment: I think code is ok. I'm sure that it is server issue.

Comment: Please show your application/config/routes.php file contents.

Comment: I have changed nothing in routes.php file except default controller.

Comment: Check your casing, is your local pc Windows, Linux is case sensitive. This can have an affect on CI_Loader, Please make sure the casings is the same on both the class and the filename.

Comment: Try adding a method named register() to Login, if that works you need to add register in the route file.  CI docs http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Rewrite rules are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can check two options. First: check whether your Rewrite modules is enable or not. Second: check your .htaccess file.

I am strongly recommend to check the second option. Remember your .htaccess file will vary based on hosting server.

Comment: This application runs without any problem another linux server (Ubuntu 12.04). But problem occurs specific the server. And server is also linux server (Ubuntu 12.04).

Answer (score 0):

In login view you have

`<a href=<?php echo site_url('registers/index');?>>Register</a></td>`

here link has 'registers' note last 's' and your controller is 'register'

This is a common mistake :)